Как унаследовать класс, при этом сделав ограничение в generic? (where T : class)
не думал что меня так озадачит данный вопрос,но при создании generic класс public class ComponentFilter<T> : IComponentContainer мне нужно сделать ограничение в виде where T : class, при этом так же унаследовав IComponentContainer.

Собственно, вы ответ уже в вопросе написали почти целиком. Как-то так это делается.
public class ComponentFilter<T> : IComponentContainer where T : class
{
    // ...
}

